# Проверка меня в очереди проверок палится

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Я видел, что на сайте бывают вопросы с удалённых учёток, но вот чтоб без юзернейма — ни разу не было. И это позволяет сразу догадаться, что меня проверяют, даже без чтения самого вопроса

(Даже если вдруг [так-задумано], какой смысл подделывать едва приметную дату вопроса и при этом косячить в юзернейме?)

[image]

Comment: Очень волновался и боялся завалить проверку, но таки прошёл))) https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf6Jp.png