# SO и частично скрытые юзеры

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Всем доброго!
Проверял я тут вопросы из очереди проверок и наткнулся на довольно интересный (первый) [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/701129), заданный — никем...

Правда, при переходе в [сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80), оказалось, что владелец вопроса таки существует.

| Очередь проверок | Сам вопрос |
| --- | --- |
| [image: img1] | [image: img2] |

Также отличаются данные на счетчике голосов у поста.
Это лаг, или есть способы воздействовать на видимость своего профиля?

Comment: Аудит... Пройдите проверку, и вам покажет автора.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6593